# Warp framework automatically converts theme for RTL. How disable it?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I use `warp framework 7`. After developing theme for persian (rtl language), I had to install joomla language pack for persian.  When i activate it for frontend, warp framework converts every 'left' to 'right' and every 'ltr' to 'rtl' automatically in `less` files while compiling to `css`. But i don't need this feature **now**!

Can i disable it? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. just should edit this file:
`TEMPLATE_FOLDER\warp\systems\joomla\src\Warp\Joomla\Helper\SystemHelper.php`

I changed `$this['config']['direction']   = $this['config']['direction'];` to `$this['config']['direction']   = 'ltr';`.

This will disable auto converting everything in RTL activated sites.